# Difference between git stash pop and git stash apply

Tags: git, git-stash

I've been using `git stash pop` for quite some time. I recently found out about the `git stash apply` command. When I tried it out, it seemed to work the same as `git stash pop`.

What is the difference between `git stash pop` and `git stash apply`?

Answer (score 2485, accepted):

`git stash pop` **throws away** the (topmost, by default) stash after applying it, whereas `git stash apply` **leaves it in the stash list** for possible later reuse (or you can then `git stash drop` it).

This happens unless there are conflicts after `git stash pop`, in which case it will not remove the stash, leaving it to behave exactly like `git stash apply`.

Another way to look at it: `git stash pop` is `git stash apply && git stash drop`.

Comment: as @briankip's answer notes below, if there are conflicts when a stash is popped, pop will not remove the stash (and will behave exactly like apply)

Comment: It seems that even if the unstaged changes in your branch are the same as `git stash pop`'s result, you will still get a conflict error.

Answer (score 101):

Got this helpful link that states the difference, as John Zwinck has stated and a drawback of `git stash pop`.

> For instance, say your stashed changes conflict with other changes that you’ve made since you first created the stash. Both pop and apply will helpfully trigger merge conflict resolution mode, allowing you to nicely resolve such conflicts… and neither will get rid of the stash, even though perhaps you’re expecting pop too. Since a lot of people expect stashes to just be a simple stack, this often leads to them popping the same stash accidentally later because they thought it was gone.

Link: http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/git-stash-pop-considered-harmful/

Comment: The fact of a stash lingering when a pop failed really isn't a drawback, even though it may seem that way at first.

Answer (score 98):

`git stash pop` applies the top stashed element and removes it from the stack. `git stash apply` does the same, but leaves it in the stash stack.

Answer (score 64):

Seeing it in action might help you better understanding the difference.

Assuming we're working on `master` branch and have a file `hello.txt` that contains "Hello" string.

Let's modify the file and add " world" string to it. Now you want to move to a different branch to fix a minor bug you've just found, so you need to `stash` your changes:

```
git stash
```

You moved to the other branch, fixed the bug and now you're ready to continue working on your `master` branch, so you `pop` the changes:

```
git stash pop
```

Now if you try to review the stash content you'll get:

```
$ git stash show -p
No stash found.
```

However, if you use `git stash apply` instead, you'll get the stashed content but you'll also keep it:

```
$ git stash show -p
diff --git a/hello.txt b/hello.txt
index e965047..802992c 100644
--- a/hello.txt
+++ b/hello.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello
+Hello world
```

So `pop` is just like stack's pop - it actually removes the element once it's popped, while `apply` is more like *peek*.

Answer (score 57):

Quick Answer:

`git stash pop` -> remove from the stash list

`git stash apply` -> keep it in the stash list

Answer (score 55):

Assuming there will be no errors thrown, and you want to work on the top stash item in the list of available stashes:

`git stash pop` = `git stash apply` + `git stash drop`

Answer (score 18):

In `git` **stash** is a storage area where current changed files can be moved.

`stash` area is useful when you want to pull some changes from `git` repository and detected some changes in some mutual files available in `git` repo.

```
git stash apply //apply the changes without removing stored files from stash area.

git stash pop  // apply the changes as well as remove stored files from stash area.
```

> Note :- `git apply` only apply the changes from stash area while `git pop` apply as well as remove change from `stash` area.

Answer (score 17):

You can think in that same way, this is how I learned:

`git stash pop -> ctrl + x, ctrl + v`. (cut and paste)

`git stash apply -> ctrl + c, ctrl + v`. (copy and paste)

Answer (score 6):

**Git Stash `Pop vs apply` Working**

If you want to apply your top stashed changes to current non-staged change and delete that stash as well, then you should go for `git stash pop`.

```
# apply the top stashed changes and delete it from git stash area.
git stash pop
```

But if you are want to apply your top stashed changes to current non-staged change without deleting it, then you should go for `git stash apply`.

> Note : You can relate this case with `Stack` class `pop()` and `peek()` methods, where pop change the top by decrements (top = top-1) but `peek()` only able to get the top element.