# How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?

Tags: git, git-commit

I made some updates on my local machine, pushed them to a remote repository, and now I'm trying to pull the changes to the server and I get the message;

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
wp-content/w3tc-config/master.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

So I ran,

```
git checkout -- wp-content/w3tc-config/master.php
```

and tried again and I get the same message. I'm assuming that `w3tc` changed something in the config file on the server. I don't care whether the local copy or remote copy goes on the server (I suppose the remote one is best), I just want to be able to merge the rest of my changes (plugin updates).

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore error on git pull about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-to-ignore-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-m)

Comment: This is a more explicit question with more details and a better answer. I think it's valuable to keep this one around. Yes, the other one was technically asked first, but removing this one would make it more difficult for people to find the answers they're looking for.

Answer (score 1845, accepted):

You can't merge with local modifications. Git protects you from losing potentially important changes.

You have three options:

- ### Commit the change using

  ```
  git commit -m "My message"
  ```
- ### Stash it.

  Stashing acts as a stack, where you can push changes, and you pop them in reverse order.

  To stash, type

  ```
  git stash
  ```

  Do the merge, and then pull the stash:

  ```
  git stash pop
  ```
- ### Discard the local changes

  using `git reset --hard`
  or `git checkout -t -f remote/branch`

  ### Or: Discard local changes for a specific file

  using `git checkout filename`

Comment: @Mellowcandle tried it. Not working for me. git checkout <filename> is also not working! Confused!! I'm doing a full clone to another directory and manually putting in non-indexed files one by one. This freaks me!

Comment: By default `git stash` will not stash files for which there are no history. So if you have files which you have not yet added but which would be overwritten or "created" by the merge, then the merge will still block.  In that situation, you can use `git stash -u` to stash uncommitted files too.  Or you can just delete them!

Comment: running `git clean -dfx` was a terrible idea. Removed some .gitignored files I actually needed.

Comment: I have encountered a situation where a user, after doing ```git reset --hard```, still had unmerged changes!

Comment: Just a note. I was having trouble with .gitignore not being in-sync with the origin. I had been using 
`git update-index --assume-unchanged C:\...\.gitignore`
I had to change it to track changes again so I could use `git stash` as in:
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged C:\...\.gitignore`
Then the above worked great!

Comment: Discard local changes for a specific file using `git checkout filename` awesome point

Comment: But what if I want to keep the changes? And not have my changes overwritten?

Comment: but why in egit (eclipse git plugin), I can merge with origin/master even my local branch has uncommitted change?

Comment: I find this rather confusing. I came across this page looking for instructions to MERGE my local changes with the remote changes, which seems to be actually the whole reason anyone even needs git. Otherwise, we could just email our changes back and forth. I used your "git stash" "solution" and I'm worse off: CONFLICT: Merge conflict...
I have "Unmerged paths" and two options - to unstage or to mark resolution. I've solved nothing.

Answer (score 129):

```
git stash
git pull <remote name> <remote branch name> (or) switch branch
git stash apply --index
```

The first command stores your changes temporarily in [the stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) and removes them from the working directory.

The second command switches branches.

The third command restores the changes which you have stored in the stash (the `--index` option is useful to make sure that staged files are still staged).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286075/difference-between-git-stash-pop-and-git-stash-apply, can be useful as well

Comment: to explain @vikramvi's point: we can also use `git stash pop` instead of `git stash apply`. The former removes it from stash while the latter still keeps it there

Answer (score 57):

You can try one of the following methods:

#### rebase

For simple changes try rebasing on top of it while pulling the changes, e.g.

```
git pull origin master -r
```

So it'll apply your current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching.

This is equivalent to: `checkout master`, `fetch` and `rebase origin/master` git commands.

> This is a potentially dangerous mode of operation. It rewrites history, which does not bode well when you published that history already. Do not use this option unless you have read [`git-rebase(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) carefully.

---

#### checkout

If you don't care about your local changes, you can switch to other branch temporary (with force), and switch it back, e.g.

```
git checkout origin/master -f
git checkout master -f
```

---

#### reset

If you don't care about your local changes, try to reset it to HEAD (original state), e.g.

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

If above won't help, it may be rules in your git normalization file (`.gitattributes`) so it's better to commit what it says. Or your file system doesn't support permissions, so you've to disable `filemode` in your git config.

Related: [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125968/55075)

Comment: Dosn't work: I get still the same message like "stash your changes first". When I type "git stash" and then "git pull" -> "error: you have unsaved changes.. do a stash first". Short before destroying my computer

Comment: @trinity420 Could it be your file permissions, check `git status` what changes do you have after stashing. If none answer helps, consider adding a new question.

Comment: thank you but my problem solved, tried everything on here, nothing worked, then clicked "commit changes" "merge" in PHPStorm and then I unstashed changes and it worked..

Answer (score 33):

use :

git reset --hard

then :

git pull origin master

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
git stash save ""
```

and try pull again

Comment: In my case I need to use `git stash -u`, as commented at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me#comment34028978_15745424

Answer (score 18):

This solved my error:

I am on branch : "A"

```
git stash
```

Move to master branch:

```
git checkout master 
git pull*
```

Move back to my branch: "A"

```
git checkout A 
git stash pop*
```

Answer (score 13):

So the situation that I ran into was the following:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>   wp-content/w3tc-config/master.php
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

except, right before that, was remote:
so actually this:

> remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>   some/file.ext
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

What was happening was (I think, not 100% positive) the git post receive hook was starting to run and screwing up due to movement changes in the remote server repository, which in theory, shouldn't have been touched.

So what I ended up doing by tracing through the post-receive hook and finding this, was having to go to the remote repository on the server, and there was the change (which wasn't on my local repository, which, in fact, said that it matched, no changes, nothing to commit, up to date, etc.) So while on the local, there were no changes, on the server, I then did a `git checkout -- some/file.ext` and then the local and remote repositories actually matched and I could continue to work, and deploy. Not entirely sure how this situation occurred, though a couple dozen developers plus IT changes may had something to do with it.

Comment: Is it a question or an answer?

Comment: @stdcall - A bit of both. When I ran into this situation as described in the question, this is what I had to do to fix it. It was definitely not a normal git resolving, and from the question, it seems as though it could be the same abnormal situation (i.e., config changes on the server, but the local has no changes). If anyone has more of an idea as to why (or how) this happened, I would welcome any insight.

Answer (score 13):

### **WARNING: This will delete untracked files, so it's not a great answer to this question.**

In my case, I didn't want to keep the files, so this worked for me:

**Git 2.11 and newer:**

```
git clean  -d  -fx .
```

**Older Git:**

```
git clean  -d  -fx ""
```

---

**Reference:** http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html

- -x means ignored files are also removed as well as files unknown to git.
- -d means remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files.
- -f is required to force it to run.

Answer (score 13):

### To keep record of your newly created files while resolving this issue:

If you have **newly created files**, you can create a patch of local changes, pull in remote merges and apply your local patch after the remote merge is complete as defined step by step below:

1. Stage your local changes. (do not commit). Staging is required to create patch of new created files (as they are still untracked)

`git add .`

2. Create a patch to keep record

`git diff --cached > mypatch.patch`

3. Discard local changes and delete new local files

`git reset --hard`

4. Pull changes

`git pull`

5. Apply your patch

`git apply mypatch.patch`

Git will merge changes and create .rej files for changes which are not merged.

As suggested by Anu, if you have issues applying patch, try:

`git apply --reject --whitespace=fix mypatch.patch`
This answer [git: patch does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply/) talks in detail about this issue

Enjoy your continued work on your feature, and commit your local changes when done.

Comment: I wanted to push a portion of code with new changes so I did : 1. created a patch out of my local dev branch 2. did the hard reset 3. pull the new changes from master to dev(to avoid any merge conflicts) 4. did a small change in my local dev 5. pushed to remote dev 6. applied patch back--> Got error: `error: patch failed: yourfile.py:33
error: yourfile.py: patch does not apply` , I still have the mypatch.patch, but don't know why it's not getting applied and I lost my changes!

Comment: I got it, the correct command was `git apply --reject --whitespace=fix mypatch.patch`, I got my changes back phew!!! [Thanks to ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375869/6484358)

Comment: Anu, the command git apply mypatch.patch is correct to apply patch, this is what I use all the time, there might be some issue with the created patch itself, and you never lose your changes if you have your patch in hand, it contains all the consolidated changes.

Comment: "git apply --reject --whitespace=fix" mypatch.patch
This command will apply the patch not resolving it leaving bad files as *.rej:
patch -p1 < mypatch.patch

Answer (score 8):

For me this worked:

`git reset --hard`

and then

`git pull origin <*current branch>`

after that

`git checkout <*branch>`

Answer (score 6):

Discard the local changes
using `git reset --hard`

Comment: What if I need to also push my local changes?

Answer (score 5):

### Asking for commit before pull

- git stash
- git pull origin << branchname >>

### If needed :

- git stash apply

Comment: Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

Answer (score 5):

For me, only `git reset --hard` worked.

Commiting was not an option, as there was nothing to commit.

Stashing wasn't an option because there was nothing to stash.

Looks like it could have been from excluded files in `.git/info/exclude` and having `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`'ed some files.

Comment: Would this undo your previous `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` request?

Comment: git reset --hard will remove existing changes that hasnt been commited yet

Answer (score 1):

Before using reset think about using revert so you can always go back.

https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1549115148-git-reset-vs-git-revert

On request

Source: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1549115148-git-reset-vs-git-revert

**git reset vs git revert**
  sonic0002        2019-02-02 08:26:39

When maintaining code using version control systems such as git, it is unavoidable that we need to rollback some wrong commits either due to bugs or temp code revert. In this case, rookie developers would be very nervous because they may get lost on what they should do to rollback their changes without affecting others, but to veteran developers, this is their routine work and they can show you different ways of doing that.
In this post, we will introduce two major ones used frequently by developers.

- git reset
- git revert

What are their differences and corresponding use cases? We will discuss them in detail below.
git reset
Assuming we have below few commits.
[image]

Commit A and B are working commits, but commit C and D are bad commits. Now we want to rollback to commit B and drop commit C and D. Currently HEAD is pointing to commit D 5lk4er, we just need to point HEAD to commit B a0fvf8 to achieve what we want. 
It's easy to use git reset command.

```
git reset --hard a0fvf8
```

After executing above command, the HEAD will point to commit B.
[image]

But now the remote origin still has HEAD point to commit D, if we directly use **git push** to push the changes, it will not update the remote repo, we need to add a **-f** option to force pushing the changes.

```
git push -f
```

The drawback of this method is that all the commits after HEAD will be gone once the reset is done. In case one day we found that some of the commits ate good ones and want to keep them, it is too late. Because of this, many companies forbid to use this method to rollback changes.

**git revert**
The use of **git revert** is to create a new commit which reverts a previous commit. The HEAD will point to the new reverting commit. 
For the example of git reset above, what we need to do is just reverting commit D and then reverting commit C.

```
git revert 5lk4er
git revert 76sdeb
```

Now it creates two new commit D' and C', 
[image]

In above example, we have only two commits to revert, so we can revert one by one. But what if there are lots of commits to revert? We can revert a range indeed.

```
git revert OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
```

This method would not have the disadvantage of **git reset**, it would point HEAD to newly created reverting commit and it is ok to directly push the changes to remote without using the **-f** option.
Now let's take a look at a more difficult example. Assuming we have three commits but the bad commit is the second commit. 
[image]

It's not a good idea to use **git reset** to rollback the commit B since we need to keep commit C as it is a good commit. Now we can revert commit C and B and then use *cherry-pick* to commit C again. 
[image]

From above explanation, we can find out that the biggest difference between git reset and **git revert** is that **git reset** will reset the state of the branch to a previous state by dropping all the changes post the desired commit while git revert will reset to a previous state by creating new reverting commits and keep the original commits. It's recommended to use git revert instead of git reset in enterprise environment. 
Reference: https://kknews.cc/news/4najez2.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It adds new information, however, explaining it in more detail here in the answer could be more helpful in case the link breaks in the future. You can use quotes as well to quote excerpts from the website.

Answer (score 1):

% git status
HEAD detached at 5c
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)

Answer (score 1):

If only one of file is updated locally and you want to discard changes from that file then you can do following --

```
// Pull latest activities-page.tsx from remote and discard local changes.
git checkout activities-page.tsx  
//Pull latest branch
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I backed up and then deleted the file that Git was complaining about, committed, then I was able to finally check out another branch.

I then replaced the file, copied back in the contents and continued as though nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably being caused by CRLF issues.

See: [Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-)

Use this to pull and force update:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout origin/master -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first answer: `git stash` with the highest score but the error message still popped up, and then I found this article to commit the changes instead of stash ['Reluctant Commit'](https://www.nickang.com/git-stash/)

and the error message disappeared finally:

1: `git add .`

2: `git commit -m "this is an additional commit"`

3: `git checkout the-other-file-name`

then it worked. hope this answer helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***Git Extensions*** you should be able to find your local changes in the `Working directory` as shown below:

[image]

If you don't see any changes, it's probably because you are on a wrong sub-module. So check all the items with a submarine icon as shown below:

[image]

When you found some uncommitted change:

Select the line with `Working directory`, navigate to ***Diff*** tab, Right click on rows with a pencil (or `+` or `-`) icon, choose ***Reset to first commit*** or commit or stash or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
git --rebase --autostash
```

would help

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with `.env` file on my NestJS project.

Tried many approaches including the ones on this page.

Finally, copied the contents of `.env` on clipboard, deleted the file and `git pull` worked!

Recreated `.env` and pasted contents back in.

In case of multiple files just move them temporarily outside of git repo directory and move them back after pulling your changes.

Answer (score -6):

If you have made changes in any of your files do;

git add .

then;

git commit -m "your message"

After this you can then fetch from or push to your repo successfully.