# Git pull aborts itself, local file changes will be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, git-pull, merge-conflict-resolution

I have changed a file that my friend is working at the same time. I did some changes and now I want to push it but it says I should pull first. When I `git pull`, it says:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
>      Aborting

How can I merge the file? If I do it would the file from my friend completely change?  I am sure he has added some stuff and I have added my stuff. How will our changes be handled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Answer (score 21):

One approach is to commit that file first then pull.

```
git add filename
git commit 
//enter your commit message and save 
git pull
```

Another approach is stash your changes then pull. Then apply stash.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do `git commit` and then `git pull`. It fetch your friend changes at first and then merge your changes, nothing will be lost.

Conflicts between your changes will be represented such way:

```
Here are lines that are either unchanged from the common
ancestor, or cleanly resolved because only one side changed.
<<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
And here is another line that is cleanly resolved or unmodified.
```

Or you could use some interactive merge tool.