# Git fetch and merge error but file not modified

Tags: git, merge

After fetching from remote (git fetch origin), I have the following commmit tree, and was working on "personal_commit"

```
---develop----origin/develop
       \----personal_commit.
```

I checked out back to develop, and try to perform a merge so that it fast-forwards to origin/develop. That way, I can later rebase my personal_commit on develop.
But I get the error:
"Your local changes to the following file would be overriden by merge"
"Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge".

But there are no pending changes on the file itself ! Please help me to resolve this.

*Notes:*

- Although this file is automatically generated, and I can discard it safely, it is possible that in one of the branches, I had removed it from the git repository in the past.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15745045/1287856) does not work because there are no changes to stash or to commit.

[image: git problem]

Comment: Since it's a generated file, can you not just (re)move it before attempting to merge?

Comment: `git diff` does not show untracked files. Use `git status` for that.

Comment: @musiKk git status says that the repository is clean.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Yes, I forgot. It's also not shown in `git status` if its ignored. You can use the `--ignored` option for that. But I guess you already found that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an untracked file `AllDiagnostics.cs` on your local machine, which is being fetched in the upstream code as well. Since `git diff` shows diff for tracked files only, hence it is not appearing in the output.

Also, you seem to have an ignore rule for the file in your `.gitignore`, because of which it doesn't appear in the output of `git status` either.

My suggestion would be to rename it to something else (`mv AllDiagnostics.cs AllDiagnostics.cs.bkp`), then do a `git merge`, and finally apply your changes from `AllDiagnostics.cs.bkp` to the freshly fetched file.

If this file was not supposed to be committed, you can untrack it later using

```
git rm AllDiagnostics.cs
git commit -m "removed AllDiagnostics.cs"
```

Comment: Thank you, removing the file did the trick. I did not find however which one of the gitignore rules was making the file untracked.