# error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am not sure how to get rid of this error. I am using "bitbucket" to privately upload my projects but I am receiving  the following error even though I have deleted all the changed files. I simply want to pull the files

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    buf.cpp
    buf.h
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

This is the command I used:

```
git pull origin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting a file is changing it.  You want those two files to be "unchanged".  If you want to keep any changes you've done (including deletion), you should either stash or commit.  Stashing would require unstashing (`git stash pop` or `git stash apply`), while committing will probably result in a conflict which you must resolve.  If you just want to revert any changes (throw them away, not interested in keeping them), you can `git checkout -- buf.cpp buf.h` to restore them, then try the pull.

Answer (score 6):

You can either commit your changes before you do the merge, or you stash them:

```
git stash save
git pull
git stash pop
```

Then, add your changes and push to master:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'your message'
git push -u origin master
```

This will help you working even in a team.

Comment: What if, after `git stash pop` I get the following message: `needs merge`? => Apply `use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage`

Comment: No problem just follow my next command after git stash pop.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-r`, e.g.:

```
git pull origin -r
```

which will rebase your changes on top of the upstream.

See also: [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15745045/55075)

Answer (score -2):

Simply delete update_dart_sdk.ps1 from flutter src\flutter\bin\internal then use flutter stable channel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.