# Troubles with git and Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gemfile, merge-conflict-resolution, gemfile.lock

I keep running into the following error with my `Gemfile.lock` whenever I want to do a `git pull` or checkout a new branch.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Gemfile.lock
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to fix it.

- Stashing the file doesn't work -- the local changes just stay there for some reason.
- I've also tried running `git checkout -- Gemfile.lock` to discard the changes, but that doesn't work either -- the local changes just stay there.
- I've also tried creating a new branch and committing the `Gemfile.lock` changes just to that branch... but that doesn't work either. The changes remain!

What do I need to do? I've gone so far as to just clone a new git repo, but soon enough, all this starts happening again.

Comment: Pavan: nope, stashing didn't work. I run `git stash`, and the Gemfile.lock just magically stays there :/

Comment: Under the untracked files or modified files?

Comment: Pavan: under modified files.

Answer (score 110):

This happened to me and `git reset --hard HEAD` from the accepted answer didn't help. However, running `spring stop` did the trick. I suspect spring is rewriting the file whenever it is modified to ensure that it is in sync with the code running via spring.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Saved me a lot of headaches!

Comment: this works for me :), looks like issue with spring when we write spring stop and git checkout Gemfile.lcok it works

Comment: This is the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: These kind of answers make me love this community so much. Saved me tons of time, again!

Answer (score 9):

After doing the following, I was able to pull and check out branches again.

```
git checkout Gemfile.lock
git reset --hard HEAD
```

I'm not sure why and how this solution works. Explanations are welcome.

The reason git was detecting Gemfile.lock as modified in my case, was that the bottom of the file had `BUNDLED WITH 1.10.3`. After updating bundler `gem update bundler`, regenerating and committing Gemfile.lock, it stopped appearing in git as modified.

git version 2.2.1, Mac OSX version 10.10.4, iTerm2 Build 2.9.20150624-nightly (w/shell integration)

Comment: Worked for me once I ran `gem update bundler`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to checkout Gemfile.lock since spring is running in the backend to sync your code in developement environment. If you want to checkout, firstly stop the spring processes. You can stop spring in two different ways.

1. Either you just stop spring using command in the terminal

> spring stop

2. Or by manually killing the processes of spring running on local, just like

   ```
   ps -aef | grep spring
   kill -9 pid
   ```

Both looks good to me. Choose what's better for you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

for me, rebasing the branch works.
`git rebase origin "remote-branch"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and I got it working by disabling Ruby LSP extension on VSCode. Then I was finnally able to merge the main branch to my feature branch.