# having problems with pulling from git

Tags: git

whenever i do a git pull, it gives me an error along the lines of:

```
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

I have tried git stash and [the suggestions on this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me) and they didnt help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first suggestion "commit the changes" should work, perhaps you forgot to first run "git add -A" before doing "git commit -m 'commit message'"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out this resource [Github Guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

```
git add . // Adds all your unstaged files
git commit -m "message in here" // Commits your files and adds a message
git push // Pushes your commit to the repo
```