# How to commit local changes to repository when there is a conflict in Git?

Tags: git, github

I went through lots of git stuff and stackoverflow answers before asking this question but still I could not find an answer.
Last link I followed is : [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

My Scenario is , I pull new changes to local copy but there is a conflict. My local copy has new changes which I need to commit and repository file also have some changes (same file) which I need to update.

Please help me to find a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases, you need to fix the conflicts manually. Running `git status` will list the conflicted files. Open them in your IDE or a text editor and you'll find regions that look like this

```
<<<<<<< HEAD  
code..  
=======  
more code...  
>>>>>>> some commit number
```

These are the conflicting regions. Go through all of them and manually merge them by editing the source yourself. Then use `git add <file>` to mark the file as conflict free. Repeat this for every file that `git status` listed as having conflicts. Finally run `git commit`.

Comment: I back up new changes and manually update the file.. Then added my changes and commit.. Your method worked..Thank you very much