# Git: upload from github to deployed server

Tags: git, github

The project was developed on the local computer then the **git push** command send the changes to github. After that, the **git clone** command project was deployed to the server. Everything worked. Now I made new changes on the local computer, copied them to gitgub and I want to send them to the production server. Again doing

```
git clone https://github.com/myaccount/site
```

And I get an error

```
fatal: destination path 'vtoday' already exists and is not an empty directory
```

Which command should I use?

**UPD**

After git pull I got error

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    album/api/serializers.py
    album/api/urls.py
    album/api/views.py
    customuser/models.py
    entertainment/forms.py
    places/models.py
    places/urls.py
    places/views.py
    templates/places/places_list.html
    templates/vtv/video.html
    vtoday/settings/base.py
    vtoday/urls.py
    vtv/models.py
    vtv/urls.py
    vtv/views.py
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    entertainment/migrations/0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py
    media/places/pexels-photo-373965.jpeg
    places/api/__init__.py
    places/api/serializers.py
    places/api/urls.py
    places/api/views.py
    places/filters.py
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get changes from your Remote (in your case github) you should use `git pull`. Another option is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?rq=1)
Cloning is just done once per repo copy.

Further: If files are changed on your remote and on your local file system this leads to a conflict. If you want to keep your local changes without commiting them you can use:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

If you want to commit you current changes just do it like:

```
git commit --all -m "My Message"
git pull
```

In case you just want to throw your local changes away just use:

```
git reset --hard
```

But there could be  untracked changes (files which are not in your repo at the moment) which can be deleted by:

```
git clean -fd
```

If possible git will auto merge those changes but it can lead to a manual merge which means you have to tell git which "version" you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self explanatory, you are trying to clone a repository into a non-empty directory.

Nevertheless, to retrieve the changes you need to use the `pull` command, you don't need to clone the repository again, also, you need to commit your existing changes first so you can merge them with those you will pull from the server:

```
git add . --all
git commit -m "Add a description"
git pull
```

If you don't have any conflict your files will be merged automatically.

Then push everything to your remote server:

```
git push
```

See this question for other options: [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

**Edit**

You have a merging problem:

> Auto-merging
>   entertainment/migrations/0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py
>   CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in
>   entertainment/migrations/0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py
>   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result

It means that both repositories have modified the same parts of the file 0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py

If you just want to keep the file in the server just issue this command:

```
git reset entertainment/migrations/0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py
```

**This will remove any changes you made to this file in your local repository**

If you want to merge the files manually, take a look at this question [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Auto-merging entertainment/migrations/0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in entertainment/migrations/0012_remove_entertainment_main_photo.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.