# I'm using ij idea .What can I do to avoid the git pull operation failed?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-pull

the information it shows is something like

```
your local files will be override.......
```

Is something wrong with the gitignore file?
What can I do to eliminate it absolutely? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you committed your local changes before pull?

Comment: Commit, stash, or revert the changes you've done locally.

Comment: I don't committed the files in the  .idea  dir  because I want push it to the remote branch and these files is forbidden to push to the remote branch.

Comment: Then use `.gitignore` to ignore the future tracking of .idea folder, and use `git filter-branch` to remove the history of .idea folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-pull%5D+your+local+files+will+be+overwritten

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the `.gitignore` it means that you have changes which are not committed while others have been modifying the same file in the remote repository.

Commit your changes and then perform the pull

```
# add your files to the staging area
git add . (or any other file that you need)

git commit

# now pull
git pull
```

Or if you dont wish to commit:

```
git stash 

# now pull
git pull
```

---

> I don't committed the files in the .idea dir because I want to push it to the remote branch and these files is forbidden to push to the remote branch.

- If you did not add those to the gitignore add them
- If they are already commited remove them from the index

  ```
  # remve the commited files
  git rm --cached <file list>
  ```

Or if you wish to remove them completely from the history use

BFG - https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

### [image]

Use this ignore file from now on:

https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij

---

Comment: Sure, if it helped you,you should accept the answer. Appricated