# Gt checkout troubleshot

Tags: git

I have made a clone of a git repository.
After I have made a new branch from an another branch for exemple branch B from branch A.
Then, I have make a lot of modificatons in my code inside the branch B 
And, I wanted checkout on the previous branch, branch A.
Surprise ! Git checkout without aks if I want stash my work and when I was switched   on branch A. All the modifications writed on branch B are on branch A.

How its possible?
I have try with command line and from the IDE phpStorm, same result
I work on windows 10.

help me :)

Comment: Not a bug: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current-branch)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than immediately closing this as a duplicate of [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452), let's try a slightly different approach.

> ... I have made a new branch from an another branch for example branch B from branch A.

That is, you ran:

```
git checkout branch-a
git checkout -b branch-b
```

or:

```
git checkout -b branch-b branch-a
```

or one of many other possible commands.

> Then, I have made a lot of modifications in my code inside the branch B ...

Here's the root of the issue: you *have* made changes to your *work-tree*.  You have *not* changed any *branch*.  Branch B is still exactly the same as Branch A.  **You have changes, but they are not on any branch at all.**  They are *uncommitted* changes.

The tricky bit here is that Git has little concern for branch *names*.  What Git cares about are *commits*.

Each commit has a big ugly hash ID, such as [`08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08da6496b61341ec45eac36afcc8f94242763468).  That hash ID is, in effect, the true name of the commit.  All other names are just ways to come up with the hash ID.

The commit itself stores things.  Once you make a commit, it stores a snapshot of all of the files you've committed.  This snapshot can never be changed—not one bit.  The hash ID, which *seems* random, is actually a cryptographic checksum of everything *in* the commit, including the saved snapshot (along with more stuff).  So if you *were* to somehow change something, you'd have a new and different commit, with a new and different big ugly hash ID.  The existing commit would still be there, with its existing hash ID.

Git *really*, **really** cares about these commits.  Git will try hard never to lose any of them.  Even if you make one by mistake, that includes a password in a file for instance, or a giant file that should never have been committed, it's *hard* to get *rid* of it.<sup>1</sup>  (Try not to accidentally commit such things.)

A branch *name*, however, is just a name.  All it does is hold one hash ID.  A name like `branch-a` or `branch-b` or `master` is a way of *remembering* the big ugly hash ID, since otherwise it's too hard to remember.

When you work with commits in Git, there is one big stumbling block: The files stored in a commit are compressed and frozen.  This is a feature: since a file inside a commit *can't* be changed, a future commit can just *re-use* the file.  So you can make a thousand commits with a big file in them, and if the big file is the same every time, there's really only one copy of the big file.

But it also means that in order to work with the files, Git has to extract them from the commit.  That's what your *work-tree* is all about.  (The work-tree has several variants of what to call it, including *working directory* or *working tree;* they're all pretty similar here.)  It's where you can see and work with your files.

The files in your work-tree are not a commit.  Changing them has no effect on any existing commit.  So you can change them all you like, and nothing has happened in *Git*.  Things have only happened in your work-tree, which right now is just for you to mess about with however you like.

When you go to make a *new* commit, there's something else tricky.  Git doesn't make new commits from your work-tree!  This is kind of peculiar—most other version control systems *do* make new commits from your work-tree.  But Git is different: it makes new commits from something it calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.

The index starts out holding copies of all the files from the *commit* you selected when you did a `git checkout`.<sup>2</sup>  You have to copy any updated files back *into* the index, using `git add`, to get the updated versions to be used in the next commit.

Hence, this thing with the three names—index, staging area, and cache—can perhaps best be described as your proposed *next* commit.  When you run `git commit`, Git will freeze whatever is in the index into the new commit.

But right now, both names, `branch-a` and `branch-b`, name the *same* commit.  So when you do:

```
git checkout branch-a
```

Git checks the actual hash ID and sees that it's the *same* commit.  Nothing has to be done, so Git just updates its special file named `HEAD` to put the name `branch-a` into it.<sup>3</sup>  You have not changed *commits*, but now you are on `branch-a`.  Run:

```
git checkout branch-b
```

and you still have not changed commits, but now `HEAD` has `branch-b` in it so you're on `branch-b`.

Once you `git add` your files and then `git commit`, you will have a new commit, with a new big ugly hash ID.  Git will store the *new* commit's hash ID into whichever *name* is in `HEAD`, and *now* Git will really, seriously care about all those files, because now they are part of a commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not impossible, just hard.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what's in the index is not actually *copies* of the frozen-format committed files, but rather *references to* the frozen-format committed files.  Since they can't be changed, this is a distinction without a difference, from your own point of view.  It makes the index take less space, but has no effect on how you *use* the index.

<sup>3</sup>This special file is usually just a file named `.git/HEAD`.  It should be spelled in all uppercase like this, even if you're on a system where `head` in all lowercase works, because every once in a while,<sup>4</sup> the lowercase `head` refers to the *wrong* file.  Git has inside it some string-compares, and uses the right special file if you spell it `HEAD`.

<sup>4</sup>The once-in-a-while today is when using `git worktree add`.  Who knows when it might be, in the future, though.