# Why some code missed when merging code and resolving conflicts

Tags: git, merge

i commit my code, and then i using `git pull` to merge remote change into local. but if i use `git push` to push code to remote after i resolve all conflicts. Git tells me that

```
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.
```

```
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
```

And then when i commit the code again. Some code remote code will be missed

Why the problem is appeared

Comment: Try to use `git status` I'm guessing it will directly tell you what is wrong and how to resolve it.

Comment: Review the commit history to see if any unintended changes were introduced during the conflict resolution process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)