# I accidentally "git stash" all my changes. How do I roll back?

Tags: git, git-stash

I am new to programming and new to github. I am currently doing my intern at a school department. I installed some js plugins today and realized I might have wiped out some of the other js files. Then I decided to just copy the .cshtml and .css files I have been working on and stash all other changes. I was stupid enough to forgot to make a copy of my .css file and all the changes are lost.

Is there anyway to reverse a "git stash" command?

Answer (score 3):

Git's stash is essentially a stack of uncommitted changes. `git stash` (or more fully, `git stash save`) pushes your current set of uncommitted changes to the stack. The opposite would be to use `git stash pop` in order to return them to your working directory.

Comment: Sometimes you forget to pop your stashes. You can check how many stashes you have by typing > "git stash list"

Answer (score 3):

while `git stash pop` works, you may also consider to use `git stash apply`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286075/difference-between-git-stash-pop-and-git-stash-apply) for more details