# Difference between git stash pop and git stash drop

Tags: git, version-control

The difference between `git stash pop` and `git stash drop`?

Both are removing the stash then what's more?

Comment: Here is the official documentation for `git stash` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between git stash pop and git stash apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286075/difference-between-git-stash-pop-and-git-stash-apply)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git stash pop` removes the top stashed state and apply it on top of the current working tree. On the other hand, `git stash drop` just removes that state, not applying it.

Comment: That is, `stash pop` is `stash apply` + `stash drop`.