# Git stash drop vs git reset

Tags: git

When I'm working on a branch and I want to completely remove all unstaged changes, I tend to use `git stash` and then `git stash drop`. Assuming I don't have any staged changes, is there a functional difference between that and `git reset HEAD`?

Comment: Never thought of doing it that way.. interesting!

Comment: I assume here that you meant `git reset --hard HEAD`. Given the additional assumption—the *assuming I don't have staged changes* part—then these act the same, although `git stash && git stash drop` causes a lot more work to happen inside the computer.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question simply.

`git stash` Deletes all the tracked files, which can be restored using `git stash pop` for the recent stash only. If you believe you have done git stash multiple times you check using `git stash list`

For the question on `git stash drop` it was well explained here [Difference between git stash pop and git stash apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286075/difference-between-git-stash-pop-and-git-stash-apply#15286090)

If you want to stash untracked files too you can use `git stash --all`

On the other hand `git reset HEAD` is a completely different operation. If you did not do `git commit` at least in your local machine and done a `git reset` all your staged files will be unstaged again. Means if you do a `git add file.test` and did a `git reset HEAD` it will unstage all the files. Pointing to the HEAD commit in you local machine. So think before working on this command.

It's not a dangerous command but you can see the difference using the `git reflog`, which helps in understanding where the HEAD is pointing in your local and origin.

Answer (score 3):

`man git-stash`

> Save your local modifications to a new stash, and run git reset --hard to revert them.

There is no difference as it does exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Well... first of all, `git reset HEAD` won't actually remove your unstaged changes.  `git reset --hard HEAD` would (though it still won't remove untracked files).  The important point is, `reset`s primary focus is on *updating the index* - i.e. you would use it to *unstage* changes.

The most direct procedure to clear unstaged changes would be

```
git checkout -- .
git clean -f
```

The first command discards unstaged changes from tracked files, and the second removes untracked files (though you may want to do a `git clean -n` first, to make sure you're not forgetting a file; because once you delete an untracked file, `git` can't do anything to help you recover it).

I would say that using `stash` is a hack - it doesn't reflect the intended semantics of the command - but it generally will work.  You could even give the `--keep-index` command to avoid accidentally discarding staged changes.

The practical difference is small.  You're making git do extra work to store objects in the database, and then telling it to disregard those objects.  If done often, this could clutter the database, but the added objects will eventually get cleared away by `gc`, so in practice I wouldn't expect it to cause a real problem.