# Git stash and unstash deleted my stash without adding it to the version

Tags: git

What part of this work flow was wrong:
I tried to push, was told I couldn't because of changes not pulled.
I tried to pull, was told I couldn't because of conflicts.
I stashed all my changes and reset to the repo with git reset --hard.
I unstashed my changes with git stash pop

The result is that my stash has been deleted but didn't get unstashed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286090/457268

Comment: Are you sure you did those commands in the order described? Your described behavior sounds like: `# git stash && git pop && git reset --hard` which would drop the stash basically removing your changes. I recommend using "git stash apply" over pop. (You can pick your stash number, and drop them explicitly.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/89332/457268

Comment: This is what I thought! sadly I did it in this order and have lost a days worth of work.

Comment: The above linked question may give you hints on how to recover a dropped stash. If that doesn't work: Depending on your IDE you may have access to a local history or depending on your OS, you may have a time machine to restore your work.

Comment: @AlesiRowland : do you confirm that `git stash list` does not list the stash you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely did the commands out of order.

You intended to do:

```
git stash && git pull && git stash pop && git add {your-files} && git commit -m "your message" && git push
```

yet you most likely ended up doing:

```
# git stash && git pop && git reset --hard
```

Since `git pop` is basically a shortcut for `git apply stash@{0} && git drop stash@{0}` you applied your changes, and then deleted the applied stash. By resetting the repo via `# git reset --hard` you deleted your work.

I recommend using `git stash apply` over drop. You can have basically unlimmited amount of stash and browse them repeatedly, apply them, and delete them whenever you like.

You may be able to [recover your dropped git stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git?noredirect=1&lq=1) or restor

Comment: Okay, in short is the way I described in the question the right way anyway?

Comment: @AlesiRowland I don't really understand why you saw the need for a `# git reset --hard` as that basically nukes all you local changes. I rarely use that one.