# Git Stash - Local Changes - Git Stash - Git Stash Apply - Undo

Tags: git, undo, git-stash

Need some help, I screwed up. Please reserve judgement.

Alright, this is what I did.

1. git stash
2. made some changes to the code.
3. git stash (again)
4. git stash apply

Is there any way I can get back to the code I had before the first git stash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: "Is there any way I can get back to the code I had before the first git stash." - yes: `git reset $(commit-id-to-revert-to) --hard`

Comment: BTW, `stash apply` will keep the stash, [whereas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286075/difference-between-git-stash-pop-and-git-stash-apply) `stash pop` discards it.

Comment: Use `git stash list` to see the entries you have in the stash, and inspect them with `git show stash@{<number of the stash entry you want>}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git stash list
<shows all the saved stashes>

git stash show 'stash{0}'
<displays changes in this stash>
<change index according to the one you want, 0 is the last saved stash>

git stash apply 'stash{0}'
<applies the stash>
```

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate that applying or popping a Git stash just alters the working directory and/or stage.  It does not make a new commit.  Therefore, simply doing a hard reset should get you back to where you were before the first stash:

```
# from your branch
git reset --hard
```

That being said, if you wanted to *retain* some permutation of the changes since the first stash, that is another story and would require more work and thought to pull off.

Note: Generally speaking, popping a Git stash is risky, because if something goes wrong along the way, you can't reapply the same stash as it has already been popped from the stack.  Use `git stash apply` for best results.

Comment: yeah, I do need to retain the changes I made up until the stash.